# postStart command giving ExitCode:143 and empty pod logs?

Tags: kubernetes

I added a command to a pod to run on start, 0.0.0.0 is replaced by the ip I'm using.

```
"lifecycle" : {
    "postStart" : {
        "exec" : {
            "command" : ["curl 0.0.0.0 -d'base_pod'"]
    }
}
```

When I deploy this pod the pod status is ExitCode:143 and the pod logs are empty. How can I debug what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on the google group, command is supposed to be an array:

```
["curl", "0.0.0.0", "-d'base_pod'"]
```